# How to add virtual-host and how to change context root WAS DEV Maven

Tags: maven, websphere-liberty, sonatype, wsadmin, open-liberty

i tried to create Maven project for WAS Liberty server.

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.wasdev.wlp.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=liberty-archetype-ear  -DarchetypeVersion=2.2  -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT

Can you please tell me how to configure Context path and how to add the virtual-host.

Comment: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the archetype template doesn't specifically provide a method for configuring these, you can easily start from the application and server config generated and configure the server "normally" from there.

## Example using **liberty-archetype-webapp** archetype:

1. Generate project:

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=net.wasdev.wlp.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=liberty-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.5 -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
   ```
2. Create bindings file: **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml** with contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-bnd
       xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xmk/ns/javaee   http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
       version="1.0">

       <virtual-host name="myVHost" />
   </web-bnd>
   ```
3. Configure virtual host (and context root) in server config at **src/main/liberty/config/server.xml**:

   ```
   <server description="Sample Servlet server">

      <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
      </featureManager>

     <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

     <virtualHost id="myVHost">
       <hostAlias>myDomain.myHost.com:9080</hostAlias>
     </virtualHost>

     <webApplication id="test" location="test.war" name="test" contextRoot="ctxRoot"/>

    </server>
   ```

#### Note:

I noticed you specifically asked about the  **liberty-archetype-ear** archetype, so if the above doesn't meet your needs, please comment and mention this.

Also I upgraded the archetype version to 2.5, which also brings in a newer version of Liberty (actually Open Liberty), though it should also be fine at the 2.2 level.

You can

Comment: Yes I'm looking for only  liberty-archetype-ear archetype. Can i know the latest archetype version for liberty-archetype-ear .Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: The latest version of the 'ear' archetype is also 2.5.